# Close all incognito windows in chrome with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome

Right, so let me start by saying it's probably not for what you think, I need Chrome to start with no extensions (ie without AdBlock), so my script opens a few incognito windows to do its stuff, mainly with image processing.  Basically I'm looking for a way to close any chrome windows that are in incognito mode.  Chrome on Android has a feature where you can close all incognito tabs, but I don't think the desktop version does.

Basically I'm looking for a way to close all the incognito chrome windows with Python.

Comment: Please explain your ploblem, not the planned solution.

Comment: OK Klaus, I'll add an edit to clarify the problem.